# How to put a breakpoint at a line in a module from a TRACE32 script?

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I would like to place a breakpoint at a certain line in a certain file.

Using BREAK.SET I know that this is possible for functions and for an address.

I just want to place a breakpoint at a certain line(without knowing the address).

Is this possible in Lauterbach ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you want to set a breakpoint in 
line 42 of file c:\t32\myproject\myfile.c

Then the command would be

```
Break.Set \"c:\t32\myproject\myfile.c"\42
```

or simply

```
Break.Set \myfile\42
```

Comment: Can you tell me please, my line number is decided from the script, and the problem occurs in the fact that the line number is in hex format. I want it in integer format. How to put there a variable in integer format ?  Break.Set \"c:\t32\myproject\myfile.c"\42 instead of Break.Set \"c:\t32\myproject\myfile.c"\0x42

Comment: Use function FORMAT.Decimal(0,&myMacro) to convert the hex number to a string containing a decimal representation. Assign the result to a PRACTICE macro and use this in the Break.Set command. E.g. Step1: `&LineNum=FORMAT.Decimal(0,0x42)`, Step2:  `Break.Set \myfile\&LineNum`

Comment: My problem is somehow strange, I get the line number from a file. When I try to put that in break.set it appends 0x to that number. EX: Line number in file is 19 and when pass that to break.set is 0x19. What I need is actually 19. Is there a function to remove that 0x ?

Comment: So you have 0x19 but you mean 19 as a decimal number? That's in fact rather odd and I think you should fix this at the source. Anyhow if you use function FORMAT.HEX(0,0x19) instead of FORMAT.Decimal(0,0x19) you should get what you want. Other solution would be using function STRing.CUT("0x19",2)